# How to center floating, multiline divs inside of 100% width wrapper?

Tags: html, css

I have list of tiles with different widths. All of them are sitting inside the `.projects` with auto width, and it's wrapped by another div (`.wrapper`), which has 100% width.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="projects">
        <div class="pro p1"></div>
        <div class="pro p2"></div>
        <div class="pro p4"></div>
        <div class="pro p2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to have `.projects` block centered, but `.pro` should be floating left, because I want to keep tiles aligned left, so I cannot use `display: inline-block;` for `.pro` elements.

It works perfectly if number of elements can fit in one row -> than `.projects` width is equal to sum of widths of all `.pro` containers inside (first and second example in Fiddle).

But if number of elements is bigger, they go to another row, `.projects` container became 100% width instead of real max width of inside elements.

Is it possible to achieve width of `.projects` not 100% if child elements doesn't fit in one row instead of effect from the last example?

Take a look on the code: http://jsfiddle.net/68U47/2/

Comment: Assign some `width` to `.projects` using `%` and then use `margin: auto;` to center the wrapper

Comment: I don't get this part '.projects container became 100% width instead of real max width of inside elements'. Why do you think 100% is not real width if inner elements fill in all space?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - yeah it works this way and for some cases of `.pro` widths and screen resolutions.

@jonasnas - please take a look [HERE](http://i.imgur.com/w150Jee.jpg)
blue line is real width of inner elements, green width of `.projects` container.

Answer (score 1):

.projects {
   width: 600px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
[class^="pro"] {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
}

Something like this should do it, basically margin 0 auto on the projects will center it on the screen.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to have dynamic width of .projects instead of fixed width.

Comment: Can't you just give it a min-height then it will enable it to expand?

Comment: Then simply change width to a %.  i.e. width: 60%;  Also, isn't float redundant on an inline-block element?